# Json data's string name have "-"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use node.js. I try to get JSON data from one company's JSON URL but JSON data's few strings have "-".

for example:

```
"duo-fpp":{
   "fdss" : 5,
   "fdsfsd" : 7 
}
```

this is my code:

```
var sevenres = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(sevenres.data.attributes.ModeStats.duo-fpp.assists);
```

When I start my code, I get this error: `fpp is not defined`

How can I get JSON data with "-" ?

Comment: `console.log(sevenres.data.attributes.ModeStats['duo-fpp'].assists);`

Comment: Try brackets: `sevenres.data.attributes.ModeStats["duo-fpp"].assists`

Comment: do like this **ModeStats["duo-fpp"]**

Comment: It's work. thank you.